# Does a compromised Amazon EC2 key pair mean all is lost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I was trying to find an answer to how to change the initial key for accessing an Amazon EC2 instance. But all answers I found said it's not possible. So now I'm wondering if a compromised initial key pair (if someone finds my computer at home and manages to copy the key from it) mean I have to make a whole new instance in order to protect the virtual machine from this hypothetical thief?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the key pair, but not via ec2 to commands. You will need to login to the instance itself and change the public key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: From what I understand, that is reset to the initial key pair if I restart the machine/instance?

Answer (score 0):

No.  As @datasage said, you can manually remove the compromised key and replace it with a different one.  You should not have to restart the instance to update the key.

The key pair is just there to allow you to access a new instance.  As part of creating an instance, amazon puts the key onto the instances so you will have a way to access it.  Once the instance has been created, starting/stopping it does not affect the key.  (Remeber that if you are using an instance that uses ephemeral storage, you can't stop it)

One thing to note:  if you create an AMI from your instance, and then launch an new instance from that AMI with a different key, any one with the original key WILL have access to the new instance as well - amazon appears to APPEND the launch key to the authorized_keys file, not replace it.

Comment: Just to make sure I get this… Once an instance is set up, I can change the initial key Amazon generated for me? I log in with the initial key, and then add a new one (public and private). And I'm all set? When the instance restarts, the initial key will still be gone? It's only when I restore from an AIM that the initial key comes back?